# Promise.All resolve never getting called with forEach

Tags: javascript, promise

Good afternoon,
I have this code to treat a HTTP request response

```js
// original code: const data = res.data.data;
const data_ = {
  success: true,
  data: {
    ocupacao_baixa: { count: [], rows: [] },
    ocupacao_moderada: { count: [], rows: [] },
    ocupacao_elevada: {
      count: [{ date_part: 13, count: "1" }],
      rows: [{ date_part: 13 }],
    },
  },
};
const data = data_.data;

let horas = new Array(24).fill([0, 0, 0, 0]);
console.log("DEBUG:horas0", horas);

let getOcupacaoBaixa = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  data.ocupacao_baixa.count.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    console.log("DEBUG:element", element);
    console.log("DEBUG:horas1", horas);
    console.log(
      "DEBUG:horas[" + element.date_part + "]",
      horas[element.date_part]
    );

    horas[parseInt(element.date_part)][1] = parseInt(element.count);
    if (index === array.length - 1) resolve();
  });
});
let getOcupacaoModerada = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  data.ocupacao_moderada.count.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    console.log("DEBUG:element", element);
    console.log("DEBUG:hora2s", horas);
    console.log(
      "DEBUG:horas[" + element.date_part + "]",
      horas[element.date_part]
    );
    horas[parseInt(element.date_part)][2] = parseInt(element.count);
    if (index === array.length - 1) resolve();
  });
});
let getOcupacaoElevada = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  data.ocupacao_elevada.count.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    console.log("DEBUG:element", element);
    console.log("DEBUG:horas3   ", horas);
    console.log(
      "DEBUG:horas[" + element.date_part + "]",
      horas[element.date_part]
    );
    horas[parseInt(element.date_part)][3] = parseInt(element.count);
    if (index === array.length - 1) resolve();
  });
});
Promise.all([getOcupacaoBaixa, getOcupacaoModerada, getOcupacaoElevada]).then(
  () => {
    console.log("DEBUG:dadosMostrar");
    let dadosMostrar = [...horas];
    dadosMostrar.forEach((a, i, arr) => {
      let b = [...arr[i]];
      b.shift();
      arr[i] = [i.toString(), ...b];
    });
    this.setState({ dadosMostrar: dadosMostrar });
  }
);
```

I use Promise.all because I want to make sure all the forEach loops complete before `dadosMostrar` is assigned but the resolve callback never gets called. It is getting valid data like in the example code above (`data`).

I don't know where the issue might be, but I've always had this happen with waiting for forEach loops.

Comment: This is too little info to go by. Can you make a runnable snippet that we can debug? Will it run if using your example data as `data`?

Comment: It also makes no sense to wrap synchronous code in an async Promise wrapper, but that's another discussion ...

Comment: I have to agree with oligofen here... what's the point of wrapping the synchronous code in a Promise? Each `forEach` will run to completion before the next line of code is processed. Why are trying to wait for `forEach` loops to finish anyway? There's nothing to wait for.

Comment: @oligofren here's a runnable snippet https://jsfiddle.net/9qm6p2ck/

Comment: as I read, forEach is only synchronous if the code inside it is synchronous. it only has console.log now that's async inside, but it used to have asynchronous code. still doesn't explain why the promise resolve doesn't get called

Comment: OK, if it used to have async code, I'll grant you it made sense :) And as you said, the mystery remains. I'll have a look

Comment: OK, I know what is going on, I think. No mystery :) I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The mystery was quite easy to unravel once I saw the example data and compared it to what the `forEach` was actually looping through. Let us step through it step by step!

## Debugging

### First loop

```js
data.ocupacao_baixa.count.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    ... // lots of code
    if (index === array.length - 1) resolve();
}
```

So this will loop through *every element* of the `count` field of     `ocupacao_baixa`. When the loop hits the last element, it will resolve.

What if the number of elements is 0? Then this loop will never be entered, as there are no elements. And further, if the loop is never entered, then the Promise will never resolve!

As the example data is `{ count: [], rows: [] }`, this is exactly what happens. Mystery solved. As long as `count` is an empty array this promise will never resolve.

### Second loop

Same thing here; empty loop causes you to skip the loop entirely, thus missing the `resolve()` call. See the end of this answer for a super-simple way of making this never happens!

### Third loop

Here you actually have a non-zero element, but the script never gets here, so it does not really matter. If you look in the console, you will see an error about `count`, so it has failed at this point due to a basic script error. Let's find out what happened!

### Debugging the script error about `count`

This is the output from running the example in Node:

```
$ node snippet.js
DEBUG:horas0 [
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
]
/private/tmp/snippet.js:17
  data.ocupacao_baixa.count.forEach((element, index, array) => {
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
    at /private/tmp/snippet.js:17:23
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/tmp/snippet.js:16:24)
```

### Example data error

This error is basically because the example data has the wrong structure. The example has a structure `data = { data: { ... }}`, but you reference it just as `data`. This would of course have been right in your original model, so it is easy to see that this is just due to rushing to get a snippet working.

When I fix that up and change the first lines to this:

```
const responseData = {
  success: true,
  data: {
    ocupacao_baixa: { count: [], rows: [] },
    ocupacao_moderada: { count: [], rows: [] },
    ocupacao_elevada: {
      count: [{ id_espaco: 13, count: "1" }],
      rows: [{ id_espaco: 13 }],
    },
  },
};
const data = responseData.data;
```

things improve slightly:

```
$ node snippet.js
DEBUG:horas0 [
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
]
DEBUG:element { id_espaco: 13, count: '1' }
DEBUG:horas3    [
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
]
DEBUG:horas[undefined] undefined
/private/tmp/snippet.js:50
    horas[parseInt(element.date_part)][3] = parseInt(element.count);
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot set property '3' of undefined
    at /private/tmp/snippet.js:50:43
```

The script still fails, and the two first promises will never resolve, but the reason the script crashes in the third promise is something else:

```
 horas[parseInt(element.date_part)][3] = parseInt(element.count);
```

There is a `count` field in each element, but you also try to parse the `date_part` field of each element, but the example data has no such field. That means you are really trying to do `parseInt(undefined)`, which evalues to `NaN` and then try to look up the third index of `NaN`, which of course fails.

## Takeaways

1. Check your algorithm for edge cases. What happens if you loop through an empty array, will it still resolve? Typically always make sure you have a little block like:

```
if(!loop.length) { return resolve(); }
```

2. Check your data model. Am I referencing and relying on fields that are *guaranteed* to exist or just *might* exist.
3. See if you can rewrite looping code to something that does not rely on branching logic.

### Tip on looping logic

As discussed, no part of your snippet has logic that makes sense to wrap in a Promise, as it is all normal blocking code. But you mentioned that the for loops *might* contain some async code, and then you could rewrite it to have something that works with empty lists as well.

#### Todays basic logic (with a bugfix):

```
if(!list.length) return resolve();
list.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    doSomething(element, externalData); // lots of code
    if (index === array.length - 1) resolve();
}
```

#### Improved version that works on empty lists

You could turn this into this:

```
const promises = list.map((element) => doSomething(element, externalData));
return Promise.all(promises)
```

This will work on all kinds of lists.

Comment: Hey there. Thank you for the time put into this. Unfortunately, nothing of this is the real reason why it's not working. I'm sorry, all these were mistakes I made when formatting the code to post here on Stackoverflow. Originally I made the variable `data` from the response as `const data = res.data.data;` so it was already the data object inside data. Also, the `date_part` property doesn't exist because it is `id_espaco`. Another mistake I made when posting here, copied the wrong API data. But you can see that even if I still fix these issues, the Promise still doesn't get resolved.

Comment: I have now edited the question and fixed these issues.

Comment: @Tiago I think you might have misunderstood my answer. It is twofold, as it covers two different issues! I understood the copy-paste errors (that's why I fixed it and wrote about it), but that only covers the runtime errors. The reason your program - even with fixes - does not resolve for the first two promises is already covered. Check out the section "First loop" and "Second loop", as it explains very clearly why. I have also added a tip at the end ("Tip on looping logic
") on how to rewrite such loop for much simpler logic that will never fail for empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `if (index === array.length - 1) resolve();` will never run at all if the `count` array is empty.

However, nothing in your code is asynchronous at all, so there's absolutely no reason to use promises. Just have it execute synchronously:

```
const data = res.data.data;
let horas = new Array(24).fill([0, 0, 0, 0]);
console.log("DEBUG:horas0", horas);
data.ocupacao_baixa.count.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    console.log("DEBUG:element", element);
    console.log("DEBUG:horas1", horas);
    console.log(
        "DEBUG:horas[" + element.date_part + "]",
        horas[element.date_part]
    );

    horas[parseInt(element.date_part)][1] = parseInt(element.count);
});
data.ocupacao_moderada.count.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    console.log("DEBUG:element", element);
    console.log("DEBUG:hora2s", horas);
    console.log(
        "DEBUG:horas[" + element.date_part + "]",
        horas[element.date_part]
    );
    horas[parseInt(element.date_part)][2] = parseInt(element.count);
});
data.ocupacao_elevada.count.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    console.log("DEBUG:element", element);
    console.log("DEBUG:horas3   ", horas);
    console.log(
        "DEBUG:horas[" + element.date_part + "]",
        horas[element.date_part]
    );
    horas[parseInt(element.date_part)][3] = parseInt(element.count);
});
console.log("DEBUG:dadosMostrar");
let dadosMostrar = [...horas];
dadosMostrar.forEach((a, i, arr) => {
    let b = [...arr[i]];
    b.shift();
    arr[i] = [i.toString(), ...b];
});
this.setState({ dadosMostrar: dadosMostrar });
```